# Express.js: Errors after response are not catched

Tags: node.js, express

This:

```
app.use(function(err,res,req,next){

});
```

will work only if error was before server response, but if error was after `res.send` this function will not be executed.
How can I fix this?

Comment: How exactly is the error generated/passed?

Answer (score 0):

It *is* executed in Express 4:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('foo');
  throw new Error('bar'); // or `next(new Error('bar'))`
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.log('err', err);
});
```

This returns a response *and* logs the error.